# Method chaining with Javascript - Plus Minus Question

Tags: javascript, methods, chaining

I got a code challenge that create a plus-minus functions using method chaining. i have created the code as follows but it eventually failed when it comes to the output rendering
like `plus(3).minus(2).value()` and `minus(3).minus(3).value()` kind of method invoking

code as follows

```
function plus(valuez)
    {
      this.valuez = this.valuez+ valuez;
        function value{
            return  valuez
        }
      
        plus.minus = minus;
          plus.value = value;
         plus.plus = this;

        return this;
    }


  function minus(valuez)
    {
       this.valuez = this.v+ valuez;
        function value(){
            return  valuez
        }
        minus.plus = plus;
        minus.minus = this
        minus.value = value;

        return this;
    }
```

expected output is
1 and 6 but I only get the printed last number entered. how can I resolve this?

Comment: Currently you just have loosely coupled functions, which don't share a context (referring to `this`). Are you supposed to be creating an instance of an constructor function which inherits methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
class Box {
  constructor(v) { this._value = v }
  plus(v) { this._value += v; return this; }
  minus(v) { this._value -= v; return this; }
  value() { return this._value; } 
}
function plus(v) { return new Box(v) }
function minus(v) { return new Box(-v) }

console.log("plus(3).minus(2).value()", plus(3).minus(2).value());
console.log("minus(3).minus(3).value()", minus(3).minus(3).value());
```

---

```js
function plus (x) { return { _value: x, plus(y){ return plus(this._value+y) }, minus(y){ return plus(this._value-y) }, value(){ return this._value } } }
function minus(x) { return plus(-x) }
console.log("plus(3).minus(2).value()", plus(3).minus(2).value());
console.log("minus(3).minus(3).value()", minus(3).minus(3).value());
```

---

Using closure

```js
function plus (x) { return { plus(y){ return plus(x+y) }, minus(y){ return plus(x-y) }, value(){ return x } } }
function minus(x) { return plus(-x) }
console.log("plus(3).minus(2).value()", plus(3).minus(2).value());
console.log("minus(3).minus(3).value()", minus(3).minus(3).value());
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. but the code is limited only to use two functions as mentioned. is there any way to avoid constructer and value function in order to fulfil the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Without a `constructor` or `class`-sugar you can return an object using closed over values from the addition/subtraction method. Something like:

```js
const { plus, val, reset } = PM();

console.log(plus().plus(3).minus(4).plus(25).plus(4).trace());
console.log(reset().minus(2).plus(33).val());

function PM() {
  let values = [];
  let traced = [];
  const reset = () => {
      values = [];
      traced = [];
      return ret;
  };
  const add = value => {
    const calc = +(values[values.length-1] || 0) + value; 
    traced.push(`${values[values.length-1] || 0}${
      !value || value >= 0 ? "+" : ""}${value || 0}=${calc || 0}`);
    values.push(calc || 0);
    return ret;
  };
  const ret = {
    plus: value => add(value),
    minus: value => add(-value),
    val: () => values,
    trace: () => traced,
    reset,
  };
  return ret;
}
```

Or combine this [with an embedded constructor](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-kdcyik?file=index.js)